# React native app build success, but nothing displayed

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I successfully run the react-native app and emulator also opended.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm also getting emulator loading message too

[image]

However After that it crashes and nothing display

And I'm getting an error when reload the bundle as below

[image]

I'm unable to figure out the issue since I'm a react-native beginner.

Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Did you try run some Hello World project before this?

Comment: yes it worked. only this doesn't work

Comment: show `app.js` and `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your emulator not connected to your react-native development server. Sometimes it happen, devices connected and somehow it lost connection with the development server. Try running `adb devices` command on your terminal to check is your emulator available and detected.

Comment: It shows the emulator. Emulator loading but crashes

Comment: the emulator could crash if they are reloading but can't connect to the server, so it crash. in my opinion its better to check if everything is connected, its like a pre-condition before you developing. we can continue to tackle another problem if the device really connected. or sometimes just restart the server (the one you run with `react-native start`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe this will help someone else.

This could be happening due to several reasons.

1. Check emulator is working or if its storage is full? wipe the data.
2. Syntax error could be because of this. please recheck latest changes files.

> Personally, I was stuck due to a small comma error in my code.